# Take screenshot of web site

Tags: apache-flex, air, screenshot

Within an Air application, can I take a screenshot of a website *WITHOUT* rendering it visible to the user? If yes, is it limited to the resolution of the user's desktop?

Comment: Is this a website loaded inside the Air application or a screenshot of a window outside the application?

Comment: inside the air application - using mx:Html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only take screenshots of the content displayed inside the Adobe AIR application (websites or anything else). However you can use an external application to take the screenshots and after that to communicate with the AIR application. To do that you will need to use AIR 2 NativeProcess API (to be able to launch a native application from AIR) or use workarounds like [Merapi](http://merapiproject.net/).